# How to create a loop on mysql query and display all results at once

Tags: mysql

I'm currently trying to get the customers' retention rates using the following query:

```
set @DAY1 = 0;
set @DAY30 = 0;
set @DAY90 = 0;

SET @order_month = 1;
SET @order_year = 2020;

SELECT
@DAY1/COUNT(uid) AS D1, 
@DAY30/COUNT(uid) AS D30, 
@DAY90/COUNT(uid) AS D90
FROM 
(
SELECT
uid,
case when DATEDIFF(date(lastConnection), date(accountCreation)) >= 1 then @DAY1:=@DAY1+1 END AS DAY1,
case when DATEDIFF(date(lastConnection), date(accountCreation)) >= 30 then @DAY30:=@DAY30+1 END AS DAY30,
case when DATEDIFF(date(lastConnection), date(accountCreation)) >= 90 then @DAY90:=@DAY90+1 END AS DAY90
from user
where month(accountCreation) = @order_month
and year(accountCreation) = @order_year
)
AS T1
```

This works as expected but what I would like to add is some sort of loop that would increment the @order_month variable by one (as well as the @order_year variable when we reach a new year). The increment would go as far as August 2022. I would like the result of each 'Select' to be displayed at once. Is that possible and if yes, how could I do that?

Comment: Can you add some dummy data to work with and also mention your desired output?

Comment: This seems like a task that would be better solved by window functions. What does `SELECT VERSION();` return? It must be 8.0 to support window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your intention right, you just want to calculate the percentage of users whose account was created at least 1 day (30 days, 90 days) before their last login. And you want to calculate this for each year and month based on `accountCreation`, that is something like

```
SELECT year(accountCreation) year, 
       month(accountCreation) month,
       sum(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(date(lastConnection), date(accountCreation)) >= 1 THEN 1 END) / count(*) AS D1,
       sum(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(date(lastConnection), date(accountCreation)) >= 30 THEN 1 END) / count(*) AS D30,
       sum(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(date(lastConnection), date(accountCreation)) >= 90 THEN 1 END) / count(*) AS D90
  FROM user
 GROUP BY year, month;
```

In other words: there's no need for a loop.